# How does Angular win over traditional Web Applications?

Tags: angular

When compared to traditional Web applications, Angular wins over them by loading a single page and altering the components based on the user navigation.So how is this done? Will the browser import the whole Angular code(All components) into its local cache? How feasible is it considering an application has thousands of components?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-6-asynchronous-routing

Answer (score 0):

Angular has many things data other web apps not have.

Two big factors are:

[AOT Angular](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)

[Universal Angular](https://universal.angular.io/overview/)

These will prerender your application or even server render so you not have to load your styles components and more while hitting refresh.